# Does BlackArch need to be reinstalled every time there is a new release on their website?

Tags: archlinux

Just curious since I'm currently trying to install it, I want to know if I have to go through this process for a new version every time a new version is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlackArch is a [rolling distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_distribution), updating it is as simple as running:

`sudo pacman -Syu`

(You just need to reboot if `linux` package - the kernel - was amongst the updated packages.)

Rolling distribution's ISO images are usually released after some significant amount of updates/fixes stacked up or when some new tools were added, but the important stuff is contained in packages you have already installed so the update process will deliver these changes to your installation too.

I'm mostly using ArchLinux (which the BlackArch is built on) and there is an update needing user's manual intervention from time to time so it's always a good idea to check their homepage for such cases, but I don't see such notices on BlackArch's [blog](https://www.blackarch.org/blog.html) and for the last half year of my occassional BlackArch usage no such event occured (apart from end of i686 architecture support).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tomas! I will keep the things you say in mind when installing other distributions as well!